# Need script for new login creation in sybase ase

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase, sybase-ase-15.7

I have 470 new database accounts in SYBASE ASE

I certainly don't want to do it manually since it is definitely time consuming.

Here by I have old script which I try to add logins

Can someone help to me write this script in another way?

Data present in this file will be like as below  /tmp/addthese.txt:

```
i111111
i222222
i333333
i444444
i555555
i666666
i777777
i888888
i999999
```

SCRIPT :
source /cis1/sybase/SYBASE.sh

```
set passs=`cat /cis1/prod/dba/input/. ----`

isql -Usa -SPDSQTS1 <<EO_SQL
$passs

declare a varchar(10)
declare n int
declare count int
declare Iuser varchar(10)
declare date varchar(20)
declare id int

count=1

while n<427

a=sed -n 'count{p;q;}' "/tmp/addthese.txt"

select Iuser=name from syslogins where name='a'

if [Iuser!=a]
sp_addlogin a,Sybase123
go

use qts_db
go
sp_adduser a,a,eng
go
use engcomdb
go
sp_adduser a,a,eng
go
use sybasedb
go
sp_adduser a,a,eng
go
use engdb
go
sp_adduser a,a,eng
go
use msgdb
go
sp_adduser a,a,eng
go


use master
go
sp_modifylogin 'a',"authenticate with","ldap"
go

select id=suid from syslogins where name='a'
select date=crdate from syslogins where name='a'

use qts_db
go

insert into dbo.profiles(login_name,userid,security_level,delta_ts,delta_sy_user) values ('a',id,'ADMIN','date',id)
go

insert into dbo.users(userid,site_id,delta_sy_user,delta_ts,email,displayname,lastname,firstname) 
values(id,'SYBASE',10407,'date','a',',  : id','', '')
go


end

count=count+1

end
```

Comment: 1) there's no way that 'old' script could have ever added logins to Sybase ASE as there's a lot of invalid syntax going on; 2) if you're working with Sybase ASE then I'd suggest you remove the `sybase-sql-anywhere` and `sybase-central` tags, and possibly consider adding `sybase-ase`; 3) I'd also suggest you provide a sample of the data from the `/tmp/addthese.txt` file

Comment: Hi mark,  It will be like i111111
i222222
i333333
i444444
i555555
i666666
i777777
i888888
i999999

Comment: please add that sample data to your original post; in particular we need to know if those values (i111111, i222222) are on separate lines or concatenated into one very long line; also, I'm not sure what the `'sed -n ...'` is supposed to be doing in this case so an example of what you're attempting to do would be good, too; thanks

Comment: In that file  ID's will be available  one by one below

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways you could handle adding a list of logins/users to Sybase ASE, all of which include a mix of (Unix/Linux) shell scripting and T-SQL coding.

One simple example:

```
set passs=`cat /cis1/prod/dba/input/. ----`

cat addthese.txt | while read newlogin
do
isql -Usa -SPDSQTS1 <<EO_SQL > /tmp/error.out 2>&1
$passs
use master
go
if suser_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_addlogin ${newlogin},Sybase123
go
----------------------
-- repeat following block for each db of interest (eg, qts_db, engcomdb)
use <db>
go
if user_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_adduser ${newlogin}, ${newlogin}, eng
go
---------------------
-- rest of your coding
go
EO_SQL

... check for errors in /tmp/error.out ...

done
```

You could place all of the above into a shell script, make sure addthese.txt is correct/up-to-date, and then run the shell script.

---

Variations on the above could include:

- putting the T-SQL code in a stored proc and then calling the stored proc for each new login
- placing the above T-SQL code in a template.sql file with `NEWLOGIN` used as place holder, a shell script would then run `sed 's/NEWLOGIN/${newlogin}/g' template.sql > runme.sql` followed by `isql -i runme.sql > error.out 2>&1`

There are many variations based on which shell you're using and your coding style/preferences.

Answer (score 0):

source /cis1/sybase/SYBASE.sh
set passs=`cat /cis1/prod/dba/input/. ----`

cat addthese.txt | while read newlogin
do
isql -Usa -SPDSQTS1 < /tmp/error.out 2>&1
$passs
use master
go
if suser_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_addlogin ${newlogin},Sybase123

### go

-- repeat following block for each db of interest (eg, qts_db, engcomdb)
use qts_db
go
if user_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_adduser ${newlogin}, ${newlogin}, eng
go

use engcomdb
go
if user_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_adduser ${newlogin}, ${newlogin}, eng
go

use sybasedb
go
if user_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_adduser ${newlogin}, ${newlogin}, eng
go

use engdb
go
if user_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_adduser ${newlogin}, ${newlogin}, eng
go

use msgdb
go
if user_id("${newlogin}") is NULL
    exec sp_adduser ${newlogin}, ${newlogin}, eng
go

use master
go
sp_modifylogin ${newlogin},"authenticate with","ldap"
go

select id=suid from syslogins where name=${newlogin}
select date=crdate from syslogins where name=${newlogin}

use qts_db
go

insert into dbo.profiles(login_name,userid,security_level,delta_ts,delta_sy_user) values (${newlogin},id,'ADMIN','date',id)
go

insert into dbo.users(userid,site_id,delta_sy_user,delta_ts,email,displayname,lastname,firstname) 
values(id,'SYBASE',10407,'date',${newlogin},',  : id','', '')
go

EO_SQL

... check for errors in /tmp/error.out ...

done